# Are Azure User Attributes JWT Claims?

Tags: jwt, azure-ad-b2c

I have added a user attribute "Role" to my B2C application via User Flows.

When I login and redirect to https://jwt.ms I get a response and on the "Decoded Token" tab that says `"extension_Role": "Tester",`

However, it isn't listed in the "Claims" tab.

Is this just a quirk of the https://jwt.ms display or am I misunderstanding the difference between User Attributes and Claims?

Comment: You should be able to get the custom user attributes/Custom claims in the claims tab too. Just to cross check i tried creating user with custom user attributes and i was able to see the information both in Decode token and claims tab. Can you please provide more information on how you are creating a user/assigning user attribute and how you are trying to test.

Comment: Hi @opticyclic Does my above comment helps you..? Can i move this to answer

Comment: That seems to be the case. I'm not sure why I didn't see it first. So user attributes ARE claims?

Comment: Yes User attributes or also called as Custom Claims

Comment: > I'm not sure why I didn't see it first. So you can see it in claims now?

Comment: Yes. It is prefixed with "extension_" but it is there. Do you want to move your comment to an answer explaining that they are the same?

Comment: @Raghavendra-MSFTIdentity Please move your comment to answer, which is helpful to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Moving from comments to Answer)

You should be able to get the Custom user attributes/Custom claims in the claims tab too. To verify create an user with custom user attributes and you will able to [see the information](http://Https://jwt.ms/) both in  `Decode token` and `claims tab`.